# Loading variables partially with scipy.io.loadmat

Tags: python, scipy, mat

I'm trying to load not a variable, but part of it from a .mat file using `scipy.io`.
The example below shows how it would look like for a netcdf file:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
aux = nc.Dataset('example.nc')
var1 = aux.variables['var1'][1:10,50:60]
```

So I could get just part of the variable `var1` from the `example.nc` file. 
Does anyone know how I could do that for a .mat file?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using the keyword argument `variable_names`:

```
loadmat(file_name, variable_names=['var1'])
```

For further reference check out the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html).